# Angular (8) - Foreach loop call subscribe and ForkJoin them (See description)

Tags: angular, foreach, rxjs, subscribe, fork-join

What I am doing is a `foreach` loop on an `array` of objects and on each of those objects what I am doing is calling a subscribe to an API. My problem is that I keep getting back (in the object console log) a "_zone_aware_promise" with the value but I can't access it. I've tried a couple of things like async-await in the function but I did not include here since I simplified my code below:

```
// Method call
nonEmployeeValidation( employees: any ) {

  employees.forEach(element => {
    element.manager = this.api_validation(element.manager)
  });

  // My loop is done i've formatted my object good to go from here
  this.someMethodCallForFurtherLogic(employees)
 
}

// Api call
api_validation( manager: string ) {

   // This goes to the service I built basically its just an HTTPCLIENT POST METHOD
   this.employeeService.managerValidation(manager)
          .subscribe((res: APIResponse<any>) => {
           return res.isValid;
   });

}
```

Comment: is your manager a string value or an object? also .subscribe((res: APIResponse<any>) is your response from HTTPClient post a generic method? 

try changing .subscribe((res: APIResponse<any>) to .subscribe((res: APIResponse)

Comment: Yes manager is a string 

As for the HTTPclient I posted the code below, thanks
'''
// This is in the service
managerValidation( manager: string ): Observable<any> {
        return this.httpService.post( 'some URL', manager);
    }

'''

Comment: have you tried .subscribe((res:any)=>{
return res.isValid;
}

Answer (score 0):

You just can't return the value directly from an observable because it is emitting multiple async calls. An async call means it is running in the background (actually scheduled for later execution) while your code continues to execute. You can however use the response from subscribe & set it to a variable.

```
   nonEmployeeValidation( employees: any ) {

      employees.forEach(employee => {
         this.api_validation(employee)
      });

      this.someMethodCallForFurtherLogic(employees)

    }

    // Api call
    api_validation( employee: any ) {

       this.employeeService.managerValidation(employee.manager)
              .subscribe((res: APIResponse<any>) => {
               employee.manager = res.isValid;
       });

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can map the employees array to an array of validation calls and then use combineLatest to have a single observable that emits an array of all the validation call results. The validationResults will match the original employee array.

```
combineLatest(employees.map(employee => this.employeeService.managerValidation(employee.manager)))
  .subscribe(validationResults => {
    // Here you have an array of the results for each validation call
    validatedEmployees = employees.map((e, index) => ({...e, manager: validationResults[index].isValid }))
  }
);
```